# Can't update my database. Visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-5

Hello everyone,
I am trying to implement an authentication system to my .netcore standard 02.00 MVC application. I created a dummy .netcore standard 02.00 app with an authentication system. I am trying to add all the parts of the authentication system from the dummy app to my original app. However, I am having some problems with the migrations.

When I execute Update-Database I get the following error message:

> Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implem
>   entation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
>   At C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\entityframework\6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720 char:5
>   +     $domain.SetData('project', $project)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException

Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implem
entation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
At C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\entityframework\6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:721 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('contextProject', $contextProject)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException

Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implem
entation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
At C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\entityframework\6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:722 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case was that I didn't have 'EntityFrameworkCore' installed on my solution. Install that + EntityFrameworkCore.tools + EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer . Then run your commands in PMC like this:
EntityFrameworkCore\Enable-Migrations or
EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Had the same issue and did this... now I get the message below but I consider this progress so upvoted this answer: Unable to create an object of type 'MyContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728